# can a full ram-disk cause swapping?

Tags: swap, tmpfs, ramdisk

I have a application that is using `/opt/otrs/var/tmp` for caching a lot of temporary data. The vendor suggest that one option could be also to put  this directory on a ramdisk (If you have enough RAM). My question is what will happen if the RAM-disk gets full ? Is it possible that the OS will swap to the swap partition or is it completely related to the application in question ?

Answer (score 0):

After using RAM it'll use swap, and after consuming all swap you'll likely see the out-of-memory killer kick in, which is rarely a good thing.

If you don't trust the app, worth putting a limit on the maximum size it can consume.

Example, limiting to 50% of RAM.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -o size=50% -t tmpfs none /mnt
[root@localhost ~]# df -h /mnt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            496M     0  496M   0% /mnt
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Example, limiting to 1,000,000 bytes.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -o size=1000000 -t tmpfs none /mnt
[root@localhost ~]# df -h /mnt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            980K     0  980K   0% /mnt
[root@localhost ~]#
```

More info at https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

As you asked specifically about use of tmpfs on OTRS, see also https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/performance-tuning.html#performance-tuning-otrs-cache (relates specifically to OTRS v6 but previous versions have similar, but not identical, approaches)

```
shell> /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl Maint::Session::DeleteAll
shell> /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl Maint::Cache::Delete
shell> sudo mount -o size=16G -t tmpfs none /opt/otrs/var/tmp

# add persistent mount point in /etc/fstab
```

Comment: `tmpfs` isn't a ramdisk.

Comment: Good point, it isn't a ramdisk in the purest sense (it's going to fall back to using swap if memory isn't available).  Could use `ramfs` instead, but has drawbacks  (can't `df` it, can't limit size, etc)